# Spark Performance on "Small Data"

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm hoping that someone familiar with Spark can give me a "gut check" on whether I'm likely abusing the SparkML framework or if the performance I'm seeing is understandable given the context (#rows, #features).

Briefly, I have a small dataset (~150 rows) that is fairly wide (~180 features). I have coded up analogous Lasso training codes in Spark and Scikit-learn, which result in identical models (same model coefficients and LOOCVE). However, the Spark code takes roughly 100x longer (sklearn takes about 5 seconds, close to 600 secs.

I understand that Spark is optimized for large distributed datasets and that this difference can reasonably attributed to overhead latency that would be hidden by data parallelism, but this still feels extremely sluggish.

The spark code is essentially:

```
//... code to add a number of PipelineStages to a List<PipelineStage> (~90 UnaryTransformer stages), ending in a StandardScaler

// Add Lasso model
LinearRegression lasso = new LinearRegression()
                .setLabelCol(response)
                .setFeaturesCol("normed_features")
                .setMaxIter(100000)
                .setPredictionCol(response+"_prediction")
                .setElasticNetParam(1.0)
                .setFitIntercept(true)
                .setRegParam(0.2);

// stages is the List<PipelineStage> loaded with 90 or so UnaryTransformer steps
stages.add(lasso);

Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline(stages);
DataFrame df = getTrainingData(trainingData, response);
RegressionEvaluator evaluator = new RegressionEvaluator()
                .setLabelCol(response)
                .setMetricName("mae")
                .setPredictionCol(response+"_prediction")
);

df.cache();

ParamMap[] paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().build();

CrossValidator cv = new CrossValidator()
            .setEstimator(pipeline)
            .setEvaluator(evaluator)
            .setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid)
            .setNumFolds(20);

double cve = cv.fit(df).avgMetrics()[0];
```

the Python code uses Lasso and GridSearchCV with the same #folds (20).

Unfortunately, I can't *really* provide a MWE as we use a custom Transformer that I'd have to paste in, but I'm wondering if anyone would be willing to weigh in on whether this runtime difference between sklearn and spark implies user error. The only good practice I am knowingly applying is caching the training DataFrame before fitting the CrossValidator.

Comment: Well, 100K iterations for linear regression looks like a serious overkill. 1-1.5K should just enough to converge on most datasets. It should also substantially reduce running time. Having more features than observations is a bad idea although it won't significantly affect running time. Finally using Spark on a dataset like this doesn't really make sense. Cost of supervising tasks is much larger than a cost of the actual computations.

Comment: @zero323 -- thanks for taking the time to respond. I completely agree about the spark use case (we have a substantial codebase in Java and for now it's the balance of effort to just use spark to take advantage of that code.) While the max iters is 1E5, I don't believe it takes that many steps but I'll def check this.